# Why 'include' position in Rails model affets HABTM behavior?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I spent an hour debugging a very strange rails behavior.
Given:

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :images
  has_many :videos
  ...
  has_many :tags
  ...
end
```

app/models/image.rb

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  belongs_to :user
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  ...
  include TagsFunctions
  ...
end
```

app/models/video.rb

```
class Video < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  include TagsFunctions
  ...
  belongs_to :user
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  ...
end
```

app/models/tag.rb

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates :text, uniqueness: {scope: :user}, presence: true

  before_create :set_code

  def set_code
    return if self[:code].present?

    loop do
      self[:code] = [*'A'..'Z'].sample(8).join
      break if Tag.find_by(code: self[:code]).nil?
    end
  end
end
```

app/models/concerns/tags_functions.rb

```
module TagsFunctions
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # hack for new models
  included do
    attr_accessor :tags_after_creation

    after_create -> { self.tags_string = tags_after_creation if tags_after_creation.present? }
  end

  def tags_string
    tags.pluck(:text).join(',')
  end

  def tags_string=(value)
    unless user 
      @tags_after_creation = value
      return
    end

    @tags_after_creation = ''
    self.tags = []
    value.to_s.split(',').map(&:strip).each do |tag_text|  
      tag = user.tags.find_or_create_by(text: tag_text) 
      self.tags << tag                               
    end
  end
end
```

If I execute such code:

```
user = User.first
tags_string = 'test'
image = user.images.create(tags_string: tags_string)
video = user.videos.create(tags_string: tags_string)
```

It will give 1 item in `image.tags`, but 2 duplicate items in `video.tags`

But if we change code this way:

```
user = User.first
tags_string = 'test'
image = Image.create(user: user,  tags_string: tags_string)
video = Video.create(user: user, tags_string: tags_string)
```

everything works fine, 1 tag for an image and 1 tag for a video

And even more...
If we move `include TagsFunctions` **below** `has_and_belongs_to_many :tags`,  in a `video.rb` file, both code examples work fine.

I thought I know rails pretty well, but this behavior is really unclear for me.

Rails version: 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may want to check these 2 lines

`tag = user.tags.find_or_create_by(text: tag_text) 
self.tags << tag`

What seems to be happening here is a tag is being create for the user but also the actual video record. But it is hard to know without seeing if there is anything in the tag model. It may be good to avoid associating the tag association with the user in the tags function.

Comment: I edited the question and added a tag.rb contents.
What's strange for me is that two lines are equal for an image and for a video. 
When I debugged my app, I noticed that habtm association is being added twice in two different locations. First record is being added when a line `self.tags << tag` is being executed and the second record is being added when a video record is being saved.

Comment: Sorry for my english :)
By saying _It may be good to avoid associating the tag association with the user in the tags function._ you meant that I should rename has_many :tags to something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is an X and Y problem since the domain can be modeled better in the first place:

```
# rails g model tag name:string:uniq
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tagged_items, through: :taggings, source: :resource
  has_many :videos, through: :taggings, source: :resource, source_type: 'Video'
  has_many :images, through: :taggings, source: :resource, source_type: 'Image'
end

 # rails g model tagging tag:belongs_to tagger:belongs_to resource:belongs_to:polymorphic
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :tagger, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :resource, polymorpic: true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings, foreign_key: 'tagger_id'
  has_many :tagged_items, through: :taggings, source: :resource
  has_many :tagged_videos, through: :taggings, source: :resource, source_type: 'Video'
  has_many :tagged_images, through: :taggings, source: :resource, source_type: 'Image'
end

module Taggable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :taggings, as: :resource
    has_many :tags, through: :taggings
  end

  # example
  # @video.tag!('#amazeballs', '#cooking', tagger: current_user) 
  def tag!(*names, tagger:)
     names.each do |name|
       tag = Tag.find_or_create_by(name: name)
       taggnings.create(tag: tag, tagger: tagger)
     end
  end
end
```

This creates a normalized tags table that we can use for lookup instead of comparing string values. `has_and_belongs_to_many` is only really useful in the simplest of cases where you are just joining two tables and never will need to query the join table directly (in other words using HABTM is a misstake 90% of the time).

Using callbacks to "hack into" HABTM just makes it worse.

You can use a bit of metaprogramming to cut the duplication when setting up different taggable classes.

```
class Video < ApplicationRecord
  include Taggable
end

class Image< ApplicationRecord
  include Taggable
end
```

Comment: There are several libs that most likely do this 100 times better than this code that I wrote in 20 mins

Comment: Thanks for the code.
The purpose of my hack is to have an ability to create a record passing all tags in a `create` method. Otherwise I'll have to add tags after a model creation.
I don't really need a separate table, as my join table is never queried directly and a relation is pretty simple. Was just wondering why did I get that weird behavior.
And I didn't quite understand your first phrase about the domain.

Comment: You did a poor job mapping reality to models. You can do that in a lot less hacky way be using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and splitting/parsing a string of tags in the controller.

Comment: " I don't really need a separate table, as my join table is never queried directly and a relation is pretty simple". Nope. You have a three way join situation which means using HABTM is going to cause you a bunch of greif. http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/

Comment: Your database layout also lacks normalization - every tag you apply is unique tag instead of just pointing to a table with normalized definitions. That means you need to use string searches to find similiar items instead of using an optimized join.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `accepts_nested_attributes_for`
And what do you mean that every tag is a unique tag?
I have tags, I have images_tags and videos_tags.
Tags are unique across `user`. 
If I need to find all images with a certain tag I don't have to use string searches (only one, to find a tag).